# Steps to create stand alone application with XUL::Gui

Tags: perl, user-interface, xulrunner

it may look very simple question for many of you. As a beginner in XUL::Gui, this question is most useful to me:

I have Perl scripts, running well in my system. Now, I am interested to develop it as standalone application using XUL::Gui. I don't have any prior experience in XUL::Gui, so how to go?

As far as i know, First I need to pack my scripts using PAR, then i have to create GUI using XUL::Gui. after these steps, what to do?

Your help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Ramesh